# How does Voice Chat work in Battlefront 2

Tags: voice-chat, star-wars-battlefront-2-2017

So my goal is to avoid voice chat, but from what I've heard this is impossible.  (If I'm wrong, *please* correct me.)  So I'd like to confirm something i saw online:  from what I heard, voice chat is only used in parties, so if you don't enter parties, you won't have voice chat.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that voice chat is only for parties, so you will only get voice chat with people you decide to join a party with.  :)